# Best way to render form from json and read the post (nodejs, ejs)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, forms

I have the following problem. I am trying to render a form which have json data as input. Then I want to have that in a form and then append some info. However the big problem comes when posting the data back. Since id needs to be unique I can't see an easy way to read that data back in a single call without having to resort to numbering the id fields and naming them different things.

Is there a way to solve this in an easy way?

input to form

```
var day = {
            "month": m.format('YYYY-MM'),
            "date": m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            "day": m.format("dddd"),
            "dayNumber": m.day()
        };
        dateInfo.push(day);
```

Render the form

```
res.render("dateForm", { data: days });
```

Rendering the form is fairly simple but the problem comes from the unique IDs. If I only had one input then it would be easy to just number them 1,2,3 etc as. But there will be several input fields appending information.

```
<div class="container">


    <form class="form-horizontal" action="test" method="post">
        <% for( obj in data) { console.log(obj); %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="<%=data[obj].date%>" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><%=data[obj].day%> <%=data[obj].date%></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <% if(data[obj].dayNumber == 0 || data[obj].dayNumber == 6) { %>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="<%=data[obj].date%>" name="date<%=data[obj]%>" value="" style="background-color: grey">
                            <% } else { %>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="<%=data[obj].date%>" name="date<%=data[obj]%>" value="">
                                <% } %>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <% } %>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Spara</button>
                </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand where your id is from ? and could you write all the form and not just input please ;)

Comment: The data is coming from res.render("dateForm", { data: days });. However that's not the problem. It's to read the data back from the post afterwards.

Comment: We agree than that is a node application with EJS ?
So if you have your route /test on POST listening (with express).
You should go into the callback
app.post('/test', function(req, res) { console.log("I'm here"); });